# PostGIS: ST_Azimuth between Points in same Table

Tags: qgis, postgis

I've seen the questions and answers about ST_Azimuth, but didn't find a specific example for this case:

I need to calculate the azimuth from point id 1 to id 2, id 2 to id 3, id 3 to id 4, ...

Table 'points' with **id** and **geom**

How can I define the query to calculate the azimuth between id and id+1 (next point)?

Or is there a QGIS field calculator solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `LEAD` window function to get the geometry from the next row in specific order as argument to `ST_Azimuth`:

```
SELECT id,
       ST_Azimuth(
          geom,
          LEAD(geom) OVER(ORDER BY id)
       ) AS azm,
       geom
FROM   points
;
```

The last row will have `NULL` as `azm`.

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much.