# Correction of GPS-Track, snap to road (line, network)

Tags: qgis, postgis, gps, map-matching

Problem as shown in the image:
[image]
I like to correct the GPS track (orange) to the right road (black).
In a network of roads it is difficult to snap to the right path - for human it's obvious which one is the right - how can we compute?

Until now I tried to find a solution in QGIS:
A. in QGIS

1. buffer road
2. clip track
3. extract vertices
4. snap to road
5. points to path
6. snap to road
   -> corners are often cropped

I also tried to smooth the line before. The problems remain...

B. in QGIS:

1. buffer road
2. clip track
3. extract vertices
4. snap to road
5. points to path
6. select by location (intersecting elements of road)
   -> results with gaps

C. GRASS in QGIS v.edit
-> problems of snapping not to the right road perists

D. in POSTGIS:

1. split track in segments of 10m (roads are mostly segments of 10m)
2. calculate Hausdorff distance:

```
CREATE TABLE tracks2 AS
SELECT  a.id, a.geom
FROM roads a, track1 b 
WHERE ST_HausdorffDistance(a.geom, b.geom)< 3;
```

-> to many wrong segments, to many missing segments

E. in POSTGIS:
I was thinking of a solution with the change of azimuth between points, but I got troubles with the points between the locations of change and corners.
(see my previous question: [PostGIS: ST_Azimuth between Points in same Table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332145/postgis-st-azimuth-between-points-in-same-table))

And now I found this: [Matching segments of different lengths](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224301/matching-segments-of-different-lengths)

How can I implement this in POSTGIS? Or is there a completely different approach (Python, ...)?

I also researched the topics map matching / conflation without finding a solution that suits my problem and my possibilities.

Comment: this is a heuristic problem under the topic 'map matching' and requires a complex algorithm (e.g. using hidden markov models and viterbi backtracking) to approximate a best fit on a fully modeled network. consider using sophisticated routing machines like OSRM (easily applicable via Node.js bindings) or Graphopper (on Java).

Answer (score 2):

As aicun said, it's a very complicated problem that require a specific implementation (OSRM, Graphopper, ...). You can also find API (like [mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/map-matching-api/)) that do that without needing to run the application. I think there is also a QGIS extension to that (I found Offline-MapMatching, maybe there is others)

If you want to stay in Postgis and azimuth maybe look into pg-routing, like they tried here: [projecting-gps-point-to-point-in-closest-pgrouting-road-map-matching](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272246/projecting-gps-point-to-point-in-closest-pgrouting-road-map-matching)

It's not like a true map-matching, but maybe that can be enough for you. But to be honest, specialized API are way more, in the middle/long term, time efficient. Because if you want to handle it yourself, even with a simplest logic, there is like a LOT of special cases to handle, especially if you use road data for exemple from OSM where the data you need (oneway, no entry) can be in a lot of different fields / relations).